# Symfony routing bundle - remove trailing slash from locale in URL: /en/ → /en

Tags: symfony, url-routing

I have the following setup:

- Symfony 3.1
- [JMSTranslationBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSTranslationBundle)
- [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle)

Everything works fine. But there's a small problem I can't figure out:

- routes are translated correctly and routes end without a trailing slash:
  `test.com/en/contact`
- *unfortunately the* `homepage` *route has a trailing slash:*
  `test.com/en/` *should be* `test.com/en`
- also calls to `test.com` or `test.com/en` are redirected to `test.com/en/`

*How can I get rid of this trailing slash?*

---

Here's my configuration:

I have setup the locales in *parameters.yml*:

```
parameters:
    locale: de
    locales: [de, en]
```

I have configured the JMS Routing bundle in *config.yml*:

```
jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: "%locale%"
    locales: "%locales%"
    strategy: prefix
```

My routes in *routing.yml*:

```
app:
    prefix: /
    resource: '@AppBundle/Controller/AppController.php'
    type: annotation
    options: { i18n: true }
```

And my index/default action is annotated like this:

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request) {}
```

The *.htaccess* file in `/web` is the boilerplate file that comes with Symfony 3.1

---

I already tried to remove the `/` in the annoation (`@Route("", name="homepage")`) but without any luck.

Comment: Did you found how to fix this ? Came to the same conclusion. When using the application using a slash or not will work, but when using the routing a slash will always be append to the homepage. (i18n or not)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to how the relative URLs work, when using:

```
<a href="{{ path('homepage') }}">Homepage<a>
```

The generated link has to be "/" or it would not work, it would go to the same actual page instead of going to the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. First you have to define route translations as empty string. I'm using yaml configuration.

```
# AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml
homepage:
  path:     /
  defaults: { _controller: AppController:Page:index }

# AppBundle/Resources/translations/routes.de.yml
# AppBundle/Resources/translations/routes.en.yml
# and other routes translation files...
homepage: ''
```

Now the trailing slash is removed but when we try to access the page without locale parameter (www.mypage.com) it's redirected first to www.mypage.com/en/ and then to www.mypage.com/en.

It's caused by JMS\I18nRoutingBundle\EventListener\LocaleChoosingListener, the last line of onKernelException method:
     `$event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($request-   >getBaseUrl().'/'.$locale.'/'.($params ? '?'.http_build_query($params) : '')));` this part to be more precise: `'$locale' . '/'`.

What we can do is overriding this listener. I've done it this way:

```
# AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
parameters:
  jms_i18n_routing.locale_choosing_listener.class: AppBundle\EventListener\LocaleChoosingListener

# AppBundle/EventListener/LocaleChoosingListener
<?php

namespace AppBundle\EventListener;

use JMS\I18nRoutingBundle\EventListener\LocaleChoosingListener as BaseListener;
use JMS\I18nRoutingBundle\Router\LocaleResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException;

/**
 * Removing trailing slash from homepage requests
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
class LocaleChoosingListener extends BaseListener
{
    private $defaultLocale;
    private $locales;
    private $localeResolver;

    public function __construct($defaultLocale, array $locales, LocaleResolverInterface $localeResolver)
    {
        parent::__construct($defaultLocale, $locales, $localeResolver);

        // If these properties were protected, we could remove the constructor.
        $this->defaultLocale = $defaultLocale;
        $this->locales = $locales;
        $this->localeResolver = $localeResolver;
    }

     public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        if (HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST !== $event->getRequestType()) {
            return;
        }

        $request = $event->getRequest();

        if ('' !== rtrim($request->getPathInfo(), '/')) {
            return;
        }

        $ex = $event->getException();

        if (!$ex instanceof NotFoundHttpException || !$ex->getPrevious() instanceof ResourceNotFoundException) {
            return;
        }

        $locale = $this->localeResolver->resolveLocale($request, $this->locales) ?: $this->defaultLocale;

        $request->setLocale($locale);

        $params = $request->query->all();
        unset($params['hl']);

        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($request->getBaseUrl().'/'.$locale.($params ? '?'.http_build_query($params) : '')));
    }
}
```

Comment: hi Mateusz Banaś when integrating jms_i18n_routing.locale_choosing_listener.class: CoreBundle\EventListener\LocaleChoosingListener in services.yml ***  have this error=>
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceCircularReferenceException' with message 'Circular reference detected for service "jms_i18n_routing.locale_choosing_listener", path: "jms_i18n_routing.locale_choosing_listener".' in C:\wamp64\www\candidate\app\bootstrap.php.cache on line 2168

Comment: Hello. I don't encounter this error. I've tested it with symfony 2.7 and jms/i18n-routing-bundle v2.0.1. 
This error in general means that two services depend on each other and symfony doesn't know which should be loaded first. Have you edited arguments for jms_i18n_routing.locale_choosing_listener in services.yml? or for other  jms_i18n_routing service like jms_i18n_routing.locale_resolver? If yes, plz paste service definitions here.

Answer (score 0):

php bin/console debug:router

```
    ru__RG__main                   ANY      ANY      ANY    /                                  
    en__RG__main                   ANY      ANY      ANY    /en/                                
    ua__RG__main                   ANY      ANY      ANY    /ua/
```

create translations files

```
routes.ru.yml
routes.en.yml
routes.ua.yml
```

added this ('main' - it's my route name)
`main: ''`

```
    php bin/console debug:router
    
    ru__RG__main                   ANY      ANY      ANY    /                                  
    en__RG__main                   ANY      ANY      ANY    /en                              
    ua__RG__main                   ANY      ANY      ANY    /ua
```